# Variáveis dentro do banco de dados do oracle não estão conseguindo receber valores

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Tenho dentro do meu banco de dados varias procedures que fazem alguns tipos de processos. Estou tendo diversos problemas quando faço um UPDATE na situação de um titulo financeiro passando a situação deste titulo para um valor que esteja em uma variável.
Aki utilizamos uma variável para pegar um valor de um parâmetro geral do sistema. Por exemplo:

```
  V_TITULO_BAIXADO_TOTAL := FUN_PAR('TITULO BAIXADO TOTAL');
  
  UPDATE TAB_TITULO_FINANCEIRO
     SET COD_SITUACAO = V_TITULO_BAIXADO_TOTAL
   WHERE NRO_TITULO = 1234;
```

Da forma digitado acima da problema, mas caso eu faça apenas trocando o V_TITULO_BAIXADO_TOTAL para o valor da função direta, o banco de dados permite.

```
   UPDATE TAB_TITULO_FINANCEIRO
     SET COD_SITUACAO = FUN_PAR('TITULO BAIXADO TOTAL')
   WHERE NRO_TITULO = 1234;
```

O problema que da é um erro totalmente genérico "Tabela ou view não existe". Eu acredito que seja algum tipo de problema no owner daquele banco de dados.

Observação: Naquele banco de dados tem mais de um owner, os dois estão iguais porem somente um da os erros.

Alguém por acaso já viu este tipo de problema e saiba me dar uma luz?

Obrigado desde ja!

Comment: 1) Os tipos da variável e do retorno da function são iguais ? 2) Dois "owners" , "Tabela ou view não existe" , alguma tabela usada na FUN_PAR sem permissão ou sinônimo para um dos owners. (se um owner acessa objetos de outro)

Comment: Conseguimos resolver, pedimos para a infra reiniciar o servidor que fica o banco de dados. E aparentemente resolveu o problema. Obrigado!

Comment: Não faz sentido , mas funfou , deixa quieto ... rsrs

Comment: @Motta o bom e velho "faz um restart que funciona" :D